# TWO SUM Question- Python. Please explain the solution, makes no sense to me

Tags: python

Two Sum
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

Solution:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        h = {}
        for i, num in enumerate(nums):
            n = target - num
            if n not in h:
                h[num] = i
            else:
                return [h[n], i]
```

this makes no sense to me, please could someone explain how it works?

Comment: note input is nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Comment: tracing the code execution with the step debugger might help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for each number in list "Is there already number which I would add to me to be equal to target?".
If there is, you have in 'i' index of current number and in h[number_that_results_in_number_+_current_number_equals_target] you will get index of that number.

H tells you what number you need to sum with a number of index of that number.
So:

- I have 2, 9-2 is 7.

  Is there 7 in h? (Why 7? Because only with 7 I could use 2 to produce sum of 9.)  No, put there 2 and its index(eg. index of '2' is
     0). (I don't put there 7, as I don't know if there is 7 in the list at all. All i know, that there is a 2 on position
  0 in the list.)

  Now I have 7.

  9-7 is 2. For me (7) I need to know, if there was number 2 in the list previously. If so, where?

  Is there 2 in h?

  Yes, there is, it has index 0, my index (7) is 1. >> return [0, 1]

Not sure if this helps.

EDIT:
This is how variables look like after two processed numbers (2 and 7):

```
i   0
num 2
n   7
h {2: 0}
i   1
num 7
n   2
[0, 1(thats i for 7)]
```

EDIT2:
Imagine, that we would have different order in nums [2, 11, 15,  7]:

```
i   0
num 2
n   7             # is value 7 in h? no, add current number and its index == 2: 0
h {2: 0}
--------------- # iteration of loop 
i   1
num 11
n   -2            # is value -2 in h? no, add current number and its index
h {2: 0, 11: 1(that is i for 11)}
---------------
i   2
num 15
n   -6            # is value -6 in h? no, add current value and its index
h {2: 0, 11: 1, 15: 2}
---------------
i   3
num 7
n   2             # is value 2 in h? yes, its index is 0, see h {2: 0...
returned value [0 (thats i for 2), 3 (thats i for 7)]
```

Why we are asking "is value -2 in h" for value 11? Because only with -2 we could get sum 9 from value 11.(Same for others.)

Comment: wait so in the first iteration, we place the element 0 at the array idex 3 right? then in the next iteration, 2 is not in the list! Only 0 is

Comment: No, at first iteration we put number 2 to h as a key and its index as a value. See edit to my answer. We need to now which numbers we are already through and what was their index. We could get their index by quering 'nums' again, I guess, but that would be painful and unnecessary, we know what we are processing in each step.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain with a C++ program. It's similar to it.

Take an array *'arr'* of size (*N*) equal to maximum element in *'nums'*. Here it is *15*. However, indexing starts at *0* so we will consider *N = 16*. Initialise every element with *0*.

Now, iterate 'nums' from *0* to the *length of 'nums'* array and update that positions of 'arr' with *1*.

```
for(int k = 0; k < nums_length; k++) {
    arr[num[k]] = 1;
}
```

Now iterate *'arr'* from *0* to *N*. At positions where *'arr'* is *1* i.e. if we have a valid element from *'nums'*, check if a complementary element is also present or not.

For example, say *i = 0*, then *arr[num[0]] = arr[2]*. In *'arr'* we have *2* that is, *2* is a valid entry in *'nums'* array. Now, find the complementary i.e *target - 2* or *9 - 2 = 7*. Now check if *7* is a valid entry in *'nums'* array or not. We see *arr[7] == 1*. That means, *7* is present.

We now need to find the index of *7*. So, store this in a variable and iterate the *'nums'* array to find its index.

The code snippet is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if(arr[num[i]] == 1) {
        complement = abs(target - num[i]);
        if(arr[complement] == 1) {
            x = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}         
for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    if(arr[j] == complement) {
        y = j;
        break;    
    }            
}
cout << x << y;
```

Comment: sorry i still dont completely understand the process